# Pass through more then one argument with a Javascript .NET postback

Tags: .net, javascript, postback

I have implemented the javascript function that allows me to do a .NET (4.0) postback

Javascript

> __doPostBack('__Page', argument)

C#

> public void RaisePostBackEvent(string eventArgument)
>   {
>             //something happens
>          }

Is it possible to pass through more then one argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a string of items separated with, for example, comma and in your code-behind extract them with `eventArgument.Split(',')`